# Type mismatch: inferred type is `<no name provided>` but SearchView.OnQueryTextListener! was expected

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, weather-api

```
I'm working on a Weather App in Kotlin and encountering an issue with the SearchView.OnQueryTextListener     implementation. I've followed a tutorial on YouTube, and while most of my code works perfectly, I'm having     trouble with the city search functionality. Here's my code:
private fun searchCityFunction() {
val searchView = binding.searchView
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
        if (query != null) {
            fetchWeatherData(query)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        return true
    }
})
}
```

I've checked my code multiple times and compared it with the YouTube tutorial, but I can't identify the error. When I try to add the city option, it gives an error. I've also tried seeking help from ChatGPT without success.

Can anyone please help me identify and resolve the issue with my SearchView.OnQueryTextListener implementation? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

binding.search.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

Comment: use this code and implements of the object members

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).